# Getting issue with express sessions and react

Tags: reactjs, session, express

**Update**
Code added, works in postman but not in react

I started react with a basic auth app but it seems that the session is not persistent. I have an express api that runs on port 8080 and my react app on 3000.

I did a login page that post a request on the api and create a session on the server. But when I request the isAuthenticated() passport method, this returns false.

This is my passport configuration :

```
      app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch', cookie: {maxAge : 86400000, secure : false, httpOnly : false}, resave : false, saveUninitialized : true })); // session secret
```

More over, when I call to another api url, session object is empty :

```
    router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.session) //returns empty
    })
```

On react i'm doing :

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login', {
          login: inputLogin,
          password: inputPassword
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res,this)  // works
          // this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
          axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/isAuthenticated')
          .then( res => {
            console.log('isAuthenticated ?', res)
          })
          .catch( err => {
            console.error(err);
          })

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.info(err);
        })
```

**Login sent headers**

```
    Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:37
    Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
    DNT:1
    Host:localhost:3000
    Origin:http://localhost:8080
    Referer:http://localhost:8080/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

**Login response headers**

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,content-type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
    Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:34
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Mon, 03 Jul 2017 14:08:57 GMT
    ETag:W/"22-SiewJVLmTt/LdfZZq/tT3axots0"
    Expires:0
    Pragma:no-cache
    set-cookie:connect.sid=s%3AE44uhyOcrptOlYWuQY6_qtFHi4dSVqrw.bPYLhVKQCO2nrVMIRr6fK5XLFT%2F0AxcmZVx86z%2Be8C4; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 04 Jul 2017 14:08:57 GMT
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By:Express
```

**IsAuthenticated request headers**

```
    Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
    Connection:keep-alive
    DNT:1
    Host:localhost:3000
    Origin:http://localhost:8080
    Referer:http://localhost:8080/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

**IsAuthenticated response headers**

```
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,content-type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
    Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:5
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Mon, 03 Jul 2017 14:08:57 GMT
    ETag:W/"5-fLbvuYullyqbUJDcLlF/4U0SywQ"
    Expires:0
    Pragma:no-cache
    set-cookie:connect.sid=s%3A0z6yb4ltDn_Ymym8XcHIt7COq_QQ4ty3.pxCBJboowCq99TKG5CmiVqj3sEA3Z9kKliS5YSgSvCQ; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 04 Jul 2017 14:08:57 GMT
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Powered-By:Express
```

This get me login ok but isAuthenticated returns false. In postman it works.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Thank

Comment: You should rethink how to handle session with reactJs, see this demo : http://saga-login-flow.surge.sh/

Comment: Even 2 requests in a row doesn't work, code added